# what is the proper way to remesh for sculpting props?

Tags: sculpting, geometry, remesh, sculpt-mode

I'm working on a stylized lamp post. I have the low poly and now I want to start sculpting out the high poly. (Just to clarify im not sculpting characters)

Usually I use a bevel modifier with subd to retain the edges, after applying those Ill use 'shift + R' and 'cntrl + R' to remesh to whatever size.

This causes other parts of the geometry to get more dense/disproportional than others. To my understanding, is not optimal for sculpting?

Should I be using edge creases or sharps to do this instead of a bevel modifier?

I just want to make sure I'm not making it harder for myself by doing something wrong on the technical side of things.  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you plan to bake the normals afterwards? In that case you could subdivide with a modidier, only sculpt a part and only bake that part, don't care about what's happening with the other parts?

Comment: Yeah, im just trying to practice a high to low poly workflow for game assets, ill be baking and texturing in substance. So would you just use the simple subd instead of a catmull?

Comment: It depends on what you want, Simple won't round your object. But again, you could subdivide, it may deform some parts unwantingly but it may not be a problem

Comment: if you want an evenly sudivided mesh, how about using an accordingly divided cylinder around yor post, then shrinkwarp. This should give you the desired remeshing .

Comment: Also you can use Dyntopo in Sculpt mode (keep a low-poly of your object of course)